# Implementation of Javascript Classes and Inheritance

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, classes, prototypal-class-design

I've created a simple Javascript library to be able to create "classes" and extend them defining instance and static methods and variables.

It consists in a simple function Class with two methods: create and extend.

```
var Class = function(){};

Class.extend = function(obj){

    var Extended = function(){};

    for(var key in this.prototype){
        Extended.prototype[key] = this.prototype[key];
    }

    for(var key in obj){
        Extended.prototype[key] = obj[key];
    };

    Extended.prototype.constructor = Extended; 

  for (var key in this) {
    Extended[key] = this[key];
  };

  return Extended;
};

Class.create = function(constructor){
    var created = new this();
    for(var key in constructor){
        created[key] = constructor[key];
    }
    return created;
};
```

Here there's an example of what the library is able to do:

```
var Model = Class.extend({
    fields: {},
    save: function(){
        return "saving a model at " + Model.url;
    },
    destroy: function(){
        return "destroying...";
    }
});

Model.url = "http://localhost";

Model.all = function(){
    return "all from " + Model.url;
};

Model.find = function(id){
    return "finding by " + id;
};

var User = Model.extend({
    fields: {
        username: "default username",
        password: "default password",
    },
    logout: function(){
        return "logged out " + this.fields.username;
    },
    destroy: function(){
        return this.logout() + " and account destroyed!";
    }
});

User.url = Model.url + "/users";

User.all = function(){
    return "overriding parent! all from " + User.url;
}

User.findByUsername = function(username){
    return "finding by username: " + username;
};
```

And I've created a js fiddle to test the example  http://jsfiddle.net/R6jGe/

There's no way to call a parent instance method or variable.

how do you think the library could be improved?

Comment: [Fixed your code](http://jsfiddle.net/R6jGe/3/)

Comment: @Raynos: you have lost distinction between static methods vs instance methods. Matteo: you are unable to have private variables share between privileged class methods.

Comment: @BillBarry there is no distinction between static & instance. private variables have no value. privileged methods are silly

Comment: @Raynos i need distinction between static and instance methods.

Comment: @BillBarry mmm... for private variables I may use the module pattern but i don't think i need them for now... but how to share them between privileged methods?

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi [distinction between static and instance](http://jsfiddle.net/R6jGe/6/). The notion of private variables are still silly. Simply do not use them.

Comment: @Raynos: I've been playing with this some now (I don't generally do inheritance OOP in JS because there is a lot of space for subtle errors) but I have managed to [come up with this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8032566/emulate-super-in-javascript/11199220#11199220)

Comment: That last [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R6jGe/8/) is pretty good, but I think it loses a little of the link between the `Model` class and an instance of the `ModelProto` class (and same for `User`; though I am not sure that is a bad thing, perhaps the need for class level variables is a sign of something smelly elsewhere). I updated it to get rid of the global errors (you get them because of it trying to grab files that don't exist).

Comment: @BillBarry I have completely given up on class models. That particular question is only interesting if you can answer the "how to have correct super mechanics" part of the question. Keep pestering me on [chat.SO](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript) to look into your solution and at some point I'll give good critique.

Answer (score 3):

I read your code several times, and I could only find few observations:

- jQuery has `extend` as well, the idea of it is sound, you could consider working with `arguments` and allow for n objects like jQuery does
- I am not sure that always overriding the constructor is a good idea in `extend`
- In the same vein, your approach does not allow for custom constructors that take parameters, whereas most OO classes have those ( `new Customer( "Bob" )` to give a silly example)
- From a lint perspective:

  - You declare `var key` thrice in `extend`, you only need to declare it once, preferably on top
  - `for` loop blocks do not need semicolons
  - You should really look into `.hasOwnProperty()`, I am pretty sure your code can cause subtle bugs by smushing everything together